# Arduino melody loop?

Tags: arduino

This is my code and everything works fine except that i don't know how to get the melody i've created to loop? Another question is how do i get the LED to flash simultaneously as the melody plays?

```
#include "pitches.h"

int led = 9;

int melody[] = {
    NOTE_C4, NOTE_G3,NOTE_G3, NOTE_A3, NOTE_G3,0, NOTE_B3, NOTE_C4
};

int noteDurations[] = { 4, 8, 8, 4,4,4,4,4 };

void setup() {
    pinMode(led, OUTPUT);    

    // iterate over the notes of the melody:
    for (int thisNote = 0; thisNote < 8; thisNote++) {

        // to calculate the note duration, take one second 
        // divided by the note type.
        //e.g. quarter note = 1000 / 4, eighth note = 1000/8, etc.
        int noteDuration = 1000/noteDurations[thisNote];
        tone(8, melody[thisNote],noteDuration);

        // to distinguish the notes, set a minimum time between them.
        // the note's duration + 30% seems to work well:
        int pauseBetweenNotes = noteDuration * 1.30;
        delay(pauseBetweenNotes);
        // stop the tone playing:
        noTone(8);
    }
}

void loop() {
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
    delay(1000);               // wait for a second
    digitalWrite(led, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
    delay(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply put your code inside a standalone function, and call it from within loop:

```
#include "pitches.h"

int led = 9;

int melody[] = {
    NOTE_C4, NOTE_G3,NOTE_G3, NOTE_A3, NOTE_G3,0, NOTE_B3, NOTE_C4
};

int noteDurations[] = { 4, 8, 8, 4,4,4,4,4 };

void play_melody();

void setup() {
    pinMode(led, OUTPUT);    
}

void loop() {
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
    // keep the LED on while the melody's playing
    play_melody(); 
    digitalWrite(led, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
    // pause for one second between each melody iteration (you can remove this for continuous playing)
    delay(1000);
}

void play_melody() {
    // iterate over the notes of the melody:
    for (int thisNote = 0; thisNote < 8; thisNote++) {

        // to calculate the note duration, take one second 
        // divided by the note type.
        //e.g. quarter note = 1000 / 4, eighth note = 1000/8, etc.
        int noteDuration = 1000/noteDurations[thisNote];
        tone(8, melody[thisNote],noteDuration);

        // to distinguish the notes, set a minimum time between them.
        // the note's duration + 30% seems to work well:
        int pauseBetweenNotes = noteDuration * 1.30;
        delay(pauseBetweenNotes);
        // stop the tone playing:
        noTone(8);
    }
    return;
}
```

If you don't know about function callings, I suggest you to open a [C language book like the K&R](http://zanasi.chem.unisa.it/download/C.pdf), and read it, there's a lot to learn for you in it about the basics of C language programming.

Answer (score -2):

在loop()內播放音樂，同時;在Timer中斷程式callback()內控制LED閃爍
例: Timer1.attachInterrupt(callback);

Playing the melody in the loop() function and blinking LED  in the timer interrup function at the same time.
ex: Timer1.attachInterrupt(callback);